# Django-AllAuth ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET confusion

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm a little bit confused by the configuration variable `ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET`. ([docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html))

If a user clicks on an activation link in an email, wouldn't the request *have* to be a get request? (Surely I'm wrong or missing something).

From my testing, if I leave `ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET` set to False, when I click on the activation link from my email my account does not get activated. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user is registered an url to confirm the e-mail address is generated. Eg:

```
http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm-email/iq4ma0qw6fqazui7ilwd4b3vftg/
```

With `ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET` set to `True` the user will confirm the e-mail just by clicking the link. This happens because by clicking on the link, he will request the url (GET) and therefore, allauth will mark the e-mail address as confirmed because a GET for this url was received.

With `ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET` set to `False`, when the user clicks on the link, a page will be loaded where there will be a button `"Confirm e-mail address"` or something like this. Then the user has to click on that button that will generate a POST request that will confirm the e-mail. This happens because allauth will mark the e-mail address as confirmed only on POST and not on GET requests to the e-mail confirmation url.

Comment: This makes sense, but can you explain why the second approach is any more secure than the first one?  Surely no one would get to `http://www.example.com/accounts/confirm-email/iq4ma0qw6fqazui7ilwd4b3vftg/` by accident.

Comment: I think it's not a matter of security but a matter of what you prefer. Personally I use ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET set to True. Most of the websites where you have to verify your e-mail address, verify it on GET and are safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source, you can see that the arguments passed to the view from the URL will be redirected to the post() method, meaning the user will not see a confirmation screen.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L213